# I keep getting stray '/302'.

Tags: arduino-uno, code-review

I even rewrote the code and it still didn't work. How can I fix this?

```c
#include "pitches.h"
void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  tone(4, NOTE_D4, 500);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, HIGH);
  delay(700);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, LOW);
  delay(350);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  delay(350);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, HIGH);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  delay(350);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  delay(350);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, LOW);
  tone(4, NOTE_D5, 500);
  delay(700);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayThree, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, HIGH);
  delay(350);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 500);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayThree, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, LOW);
  delay (700);
  tone(4, NOTE_G4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayThree, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayFour, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, HIGH);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_G4, 500);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayThree, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayFour, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, LOW);
  delay (700);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250); //Oh chanukah oh chanuka come light the meora
  digitalWrite(dayOne, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayThree, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayFour, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayFive, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, HIGH);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250); //Oh chanukah oh chanuka come light the meora
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 500);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayThree, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayFour, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayFive, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, LOW);
  delay(700);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayThree, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayFour, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayFive, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(daySix, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, HIGH);
  delay(350);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  delay(350);
  tone(4, NOTE_D5, 500);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayThree, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayFour, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayFive, LOW);
  digitalWrite(daySix, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, LOW);
  delay(700);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayThree, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayFour, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayFive, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(daySix, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(daySeven, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, HIGH);
  delay(350);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 500);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayThree, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayFour, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayFive, LOW);
  digitalWrite(daySix, LOW);
  digitalWrite(daySeven, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, LOW);
  delay (700);
  tone(4, NOTE_G4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayThree, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayFour, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayFive, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(daySix, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(daySeven, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(dayEight, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, HIGH);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_G4, 500);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayThree, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayFour, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayFive, LOW);
  digitalWrite(daySix, LOW);
  digitalWrite(daySeven, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dayEight, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, LOW);
  delay (700);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 500); //Oh chanukah oh chanuka come light the meora
  delay (700);


  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, HIGH);
  delay (50);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, HIGH);
  delay (50);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayThree, HIGH);
  delay (50);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayFour, HIGH);
  delay (50);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, HIGH);
  delay (50);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayFive, HIGH);
  delay (50);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250);
  digitalWrite(daySix, HIGH);
  delay (50);


  tone(4, NOTE_G4, 250);
  digitalWrite(daySEVEN, HIGH);
  delay (50);
  tone(4, NOTE_G4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayEIGHT, HIGH);
  delay (50);
  tone(4, NOTE_G4, 250);
  delay(250);

  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayEight, HIGH);
  delay (50);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  digitalWrite(daySeven, HIGH);
  delay (50);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  digitalWrite(daySix, HIGH);
  delay (50);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayFive, HIGH);
  delay (50);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  digitalWrite(Shamash, HIGH);
  delay (50);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayFour, HIGH);
  delay (50);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayThree, HIGH);
  delay (50);

  tone(4, NOTE_G4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayTwo, HIGH);
  delay(50);
  tone(4, NOTE_G4, 250);
  digitalWrite(dayOne, HIGH);
  delay(50);
  tone(4, NOTE_G4, 250);
  delay(250);

  delay (300);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 500);
  delay (700);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_G4, 500);
  delay (700);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_E4, 250);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 750);
  delay (1000);

  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_G4, 250);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_A4, 250);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_G4, 250);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 500);
  delay (700);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 500);
  delay (700);
  tone(4, NOTE_G4, 500);
  delay (700);
  tone(4, NOTE_F4, 250);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_E4, 250);
  delay (350);
  tone(4, NOTE_D4, 500);
  delay (700);
  delay (2000);
}
```

Comment: Edit your post to contain the full error message, in a code block.

Answer (score 3):

The Stray /302 is saying that the compiler found some random unicode character that it didn't understand.  You should put your code into some text editor that will allow you to see the unicode characters and go find it.  It will probably be a lot easier if you'll format that code instead of trying to cram it all in one line.